# Send webhook underwater (JQuery/Ajax or without opening the link in browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webhooks

I have to open a link from http://www.example.com so it saves something on http://www.otherexample.com with a webhook-link like in the example: (http://www.otherdomain.com/test.php?id=12345&finished=1). On that domain is something stored in a CRM and it returns a blank page with 'OK' in it (literally no html tags included).

Here are the functions I use:

```
function sendWebhook() {
    var url = 'http://www.otherdomain.com/test.php?id=12345&finished=1';
    $.post(url,function(data) { showValidate(data) });
}

function showValidate(results) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(results));
    alert(results)
}
```

I have no problem sending Ajax calls that return JSON files, but have no idea how to do it with just a link/webhook. My work-around is for now is opening a link in new window/browser, but I think that's an ugly solution

Comment: Sending a POST request cross-domain can work for this, however you need to ensure that `otherdomain.com` (in this example) returns CORS headers in its response. Exactly how you do that will depend on whether you have access to the backend infrastructure of the domain, and what platform it's using.

Comment: Does `www.otherexample.com` have CORS enabled?

Comment: I have a contact on the other side and will ask him. Thanks for the tip!